# How can I compare an attribute of a instance, which is a date, to the current date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I am trying to write a scope or a method where  I take the attribute (last_eaten) of an instance (line_item) and compare it to the current date.  If last_eaten has a date of 1-7 days ago, it gets put in an array that will be called last_week.  If last_eaten has a date of 8-14 days ago, it gets put in an array that will be called 2_weeks_ago.

I've tried quite a few things as you can see with the commented out code and several things that I had already erased, but I can't get anything to work.  I'm relatively new to rails and any help would be greatly appreciated.

***Model***

```
  class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :recipe_collection


  #scope :last_week, lambda {where("line_item.last_eaten >= ?", 7.days.ago)}
  #scope :last_week, lambda { |weeks| where("last_eaten > ?", weeks) }
  #scope :three_weeks, lambda { where( @line_item.last_eaten < 21.days.ago.to_date) }
  #@line_item = LineItem.where(last_eaten: params[:last_eaten]) -- returns nil
  #@line_item = LineItem.where(last_eaten: params[:last_eaten] < 21.days.ago.to_date)

  #def menu
  # list = []
  # if LineItem.last_eaten.day.to_i > 21.days.ago.day.to_i
  #     LineItem.last_eaten.each do |recipe_id|
  #         LineItem.recipe_id  << list
  #     end
  # end
  # list
  #end

end
```

***Schema***

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151229223926) do

  create_table "directions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "step"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "directions", ["recipe_id"], name: "index_directions_on_recipe_id"

  create_table "ingredients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "ingredients", ["recipe_id"], name: "index_ingredients_on_recipe_id"

  create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "recipe_id"
    t.integer  "recipe_collection_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
    t.date     "last_eaten"
  end

  add_index "line_items", ["recipe_collection_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_recipe_collection_id"
  add_index "line_items", ["recipe_id"], name: "index_line_items_on_recipe_id"

  create_table "recipe_collections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "recipes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

Comment: `scope :last_week, lambda {where("line_item.last_eaten >= ?", 7.days.ago)}` this should work... what are you getting instead? have you checked that the `>=` is the right way around? Oh, also: is your table called `line_item` or `line_items` (remember, when doing sql-snippets, you're referring to the table name, not an individual rails object's name)

Comment: ...and @TarynEast beat me to it. I unknowingly pretty much duplicated the latter part of your comment in my answer. If this solves the issue, and if you want to create an answer, I'll take mine down - looks like you posted the comment first. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scope :last_week, lambda {where("line_item.last_eaten >= ?", 7.days.ago)}`

should work...

But further reading made me realise that your table is called `line_items`, not `line_item`

When you're doing sql-snippets, you need to refer to the name of the table in SQL, rather than treating it like an individual rails object's name. This means always use the pluralised version :)

Comment: Thanks so much!  This was driving me crazy.  I had to make a small change or two.  First, it counts the actual day that the scope is run so I had to change it to "8.days.ago".  Finally there was a minor conflict between **datetime** and **date**, so I had to append **to_date** at the end.  The new scope is: `scope :last_week, lambda {where("line_item.last_eaten >= ?", 8.days.ago.to_date)}`